# Is it possible to convert a choice to an int in Kconfig

Tags: kbuild

I'm looking for a way to convert a choice to an int in a Kconfig file.   So for example, I would want:

```
config BUFSIZE
    int

choice
    prompt "choose a buffersize"
    depends on FOOBAR
    default 10 if FOO
    default 15 if BAR 
    default 20

config SIZE10
    bool "10"
    depends on !FOO
    select BUFSIZE=10

config SIZE15
    bool "15"
    depends on FOOBAR | BAR
    select BUFSIZE=15

config SIZE20
    bool "20"
    depends on BAR
    select BUFSIZE=20

endchoice
```

of course, you can't use `=` with `select`, so the above does not work.   The actual list of choices is somewhat long and volatile, so I would like to avoid having a string of `#ifdef`'s in another file to convert these to integers (plus these values are used in Makefiles as well as C files...)

My alternative is to make `BUFSIZE` user configurable, but that's problematic, as I cannot restrict the possible values very well.   As well, if I specify a default value for an `int`, and run `make oldconfig` (where the value has not previously been defined), it prompts me for a value.   If you set a default for a choice, it does not seem to prompt you on make oldconfig.   This is important, as `FOOBAR` is turned off/on often, and I would like it to automatically select the default value for the architecture when it is turned on.

I'm wondering if there's a clean solution to this that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
choice
    prompt "choose a buffersize"
    depends on FOOBAR
    config BUFFERSIZE_15
        bool "15"
    config BUFFERSIZE_20
        bool "20"
    config BUFFERSIZE_25
        bool "25"
endchoice

config BUFSIZE
    int
    default 10
    default 15 if BUFFERSIZE_15
    default 20 if BUFFERSIZE_20
    default 25 if BUFFERSIZE_25
```